# peewee select() return SQL query, not the actual data

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, peewee

I'm trying sum up the values in two columns and truncate my date fields by the day. I've constructed the SQL query to do this(which works):

```
SELECT date_trunc('day', date) AS Day, SUM(fremont_bridge_nb) AS 
Sum_NB, SUM(fremont_bridge_sb) AS Sum_SB FROM bike_count GROUP BY Day 
ORDER BY Day;
```

But I then run into issues when I try to format this into peewee:

```
Bike_Count.select(fn.date_trunc('day', Bike_Count.date).alias('Day'),
fn.SUM(Bike_Count.fremont_bridge_nb).alias('Sum_NB'),
fn.SUM(Bike_Count.fremont_bridge_sb).alias('Sum_SB'))
.group_by('Day').order_by('Day')
```

I don't get any errors, but when I print out the variable I stored this in, it shows:

```
 <class 'models.Bike_Count'> SELECT date_trunc(%s, "t1"."date") AS 
Day, SUM("t1"."fremont_bridge_nb") AS Sum_NB, 
SUM("t1"."fremont_bridge_sb") AS Sum_SB FROM "bike_count" AS t1 ORDER 
BY %s ['day', 'Day']
```

The only thing that I've written in Python to get data successfully is:

```
 Bike_Count.get(Bike_Count.id == 1).date
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just stick a string into your group by / order by, Peewee will try to parameterize it as a value. This is to avoid SQL injection haxx.

To solve the problem, you can use `SQL('Day')` in place of `'Day'` inside the `group_by()` and `order_by()` calls.

Another way is to just stick the function call into the `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY`. Here's how you would do that:

```
day = fn.date_trunc('day', Bike_Count.date)
nb_sum = fn.SUM(Bike_Count.fremont_bridge_nb)
sb_sum = fn.SUM(Bike_Count.fremont_bridge_sb)

query = (Bike_Count
         .select(day.alias('Day'), nb_sum.alias('Sum_NB'), sb_sum.alias('Sum_SB'))
         .group_by(day)
         .order_by(day))
```

Or, if you prefer:

```
query = (Bike_Count
         .select(day.alias('Day'), nb_sum.alias('Sum_NB'), sb_sum.alias('Sum_SB'))
         .group_by(SQL('Day'))
         .order_by(SQL('Day')))
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot. I was also a bit confused how to access the data, and ended up iterating over the query with a for loop.